# GTK# - printing: How to set the paper size

Tags: c#, printing, mono, gtk#

I'm printing some text with GTK# similar to the demo code you can find here:

https://github.com/mono/gtk-sharp/blob/master/sample/GtkDemo/DemoPrinting.cs

The text is printed correctly, but I'd like to have a page with a different paper size as output.

How can I setup the paper size programmatically?

```
PrintOperation print = new PrintOperation();

print.BeginPrint += new BeginPrintHandler(OnBeginPrint);
print.DrawPage += new DrawPageHandler(OnDrawPage);
print.EndPrint += new EndPrintHandler(OnEndPrint);
print.Run(PrintOperationAction.Print, null);
```

EDIT
I found out that the `PrintOperation` class has two members called `DefaultPageSetup` and `PrintSettings`, which contains a PaperSize, but these objects are null after creating (`new PrintOperation()`).
And at `OnBeginPrint` these values are already set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found out how to set a custom paper size!
You have to set the `DefaultPageSetup` and `PrintSettings` of the `PrintOperation`:

```
PrintSettings settings = new PrintSettings();
settings.PaperSize = new PaperSize("XXX", "XXX", 500, 5000);

PageSetup setup = new PageSetup();
setup.SetBottomMargin(0, Unit.Pixel);
setup.SetTopMargin(0, Unit.Pixel);
setup.SetLeftMargin(0, Unit.Pixel);
setup.SetRightMargin(0, Unit.Pixel);
setup.PaperSize = settings.PaperSize;

PrintOperation print = new PrintOperation();
print.DefaultPageSetup = setup;
print.PrintSettings = settings;

print.BeginPrint += new BeginPrintHandler(OnBeginPrint);
print.DrawPage += new DrawPageHandler(OnDrawPage);
print.EndPrint += new EndPrintHandler(OnEndPrint);
print.Run(PrintOperationAction.Print, null);
```